# "nativescript-google-maps-sdk" PlugIn shows blank screen

Tags: android, google-maps, nativescript

I have installed [nativescript-google-maps-sdk](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) plugin in my [NativeScript 2.0](https://www.nativescript.org/) project.

I generated and activated an **Android API key** at the **Google Developer Console**.

As described in the documentation of the plugin I added the string resource value **nativescript_google_maps_api_key** with the API key, but it does not work.

I also tried to add the **google_maps_key** string resource as described in the official Google documentation, so my resource file looks like this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="google_maps_key">MY_API_KEY</string>
  <string name="nativescript_google_maps_api_key">MY_API_KEY</string>
</resources>
```

My last try was to add a meta value to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<manifest>
  <application>
      ...

      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                 android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

In my **app.gradle** file I added a reference to the **com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0** package.

But nothings helps ... I still have a blank screen with a Google logo but no map.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
After I checked "Use Host GPU", it worked

1. Open **Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager**
2. Select emulator and click **Edit**
3. Check Emulator Options: **Use Host GPU**

Comment: i checked "Use Host GPU" still getting blank page

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to run this plugin correctly, maybe it is not compatible with NativeScript 2.0. 
However you could use official **NativeScript** plugin **nativescript-geolocation** or **nativescript-googleMaps**, which work normal on both iOS and Android.
You could read more about the plugin here: [NativeScript Location](https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/location)

Also you could review this sample app with **nativescript-googleMaps** [location](https://github.com/nsndeck/locationtest.git)
To upgrade the project to latest NS 2.0. run **npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save**

Indeed you should add this line

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
```

before `</application>` closing tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the exact steps as shown in the [demo app](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/tree/master/demo) and it worked correctly!
Now the first thing I have noticed is that the file with your API-Key is located as follows

***App_Resources/Android/values/nativescript-google-maps-api.xml***

And looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nativescript_google_maps_api_key">your-api-key-here</string>
</resources>
```

In the map-page.xml we have

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:maps="nativescript-google-maps-sdk" loaded="pageLoaded">
<GridLayout>
    <maps:mapView latitude="{{ latitude }}" longitude="{{ longitude }}" zoom="{{ zoom }}"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Keep in mind that in the demo the author has passed the params via view-model but
you can always hardcore the values for latitude ,longitude and zoom for test pourposes.
And thats all that is needed in order for the plugin to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem, and everything you try does not seem to do anything, I would recommend checking your Android Logs.

```
adb logcat
```

Check for the following:
**Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above**

This was my problem.  The emulator I was using did not support the stated version of OpenGL.  So I created a new emulator, checking off *Use Host GPU* and that seemed to cure the *blank map with logo* issue.

I think the *Use Host GPU* is the key.  The old emulator I was using didn't have this option, so I couldn't verify this.